# map function does not return anything in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My app has 2 components.When I pass props from parent to child then i iterate the props using map and return a list in todoItemListjs component but it gives an error

> A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Here are my components

TodoList

```
    var React=require('react');
import TodoListItem from './TodoListItem.js';
    var TodoList = React.createClass({
        Remove: function(e){
           this.props.onDelete(e);
        },
        DragStart: function(e){
            this.dragged = e.currentTarget;
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        },
        DragEnd: function(e){
            this.dragged.style.display="";
            var IshasNode = false

            Array.prototype.forEach.call (this.dragged.parentNode.childNodes, function (node) {
                if(node.className=="placeholder")
                                IshasNode = true;

            } );
            if(!IshasNode)
            return;
            this.dragged.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);
            var data = this.props.items;
            var from = Number(this.dragged.dataset.id);
            var to = Number(this.over.dataset.id);
            if(from < to) to--;
            if(this.nodePlacement == "after") to++;
            data.splice(to, 0, data.splice(from, 1)[0]);
            this.setState({data: data});    
        },
        DragOver: function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            this.dragged.style.display = "none";

            if(e.target.className == "placeholder") return;
            this.over = e.target;

            var relY = e.clientY - this.over.offsetTop;
            var height = this.over.offsetHeight / 2;
            var parent = e.target.parentNode;

            if(relY > height) {
              this.nodePlacement = "after";
              parent.insertBefore(placeholder, e.target.nextElementSibling);
            }
            else if(relY < height) {
              this.nodePlacement = "before"
              parent.insertBefore(placeholder, e.target);
            }
        },
        render: function() {

            var createItem = function(itemText,i) {


                return (

                    <TodoListItem key={i} value={i} onDragEnd={this.DragEnd}
            onDragStart={this.DragStart} onRemove = {this.Remove} AllItems={itemText}>{itemText}</TodoListItem>


                );
            };
            var allitems = this.props.items;
            // Here is the filter function 
            var status = this.props.filter[0].Status;
            switch (status){
                case 'false':
                 allitems = allitems.filter(t => !t.isDone)
                 break;
                 case 'true':
                 allitems = allitems.filter(t => t.isDone)
            };
            // Here is the search function 
            var queryText = this.props.filter[0].keyword;

            if(queryText){
                var queryResult=[];
                allitems.forEach(function(item){
                    if(item.item.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryText)!=-1)
                    queryResult.push(item);
                });
                return <ul onDragOver={this.DragOver}>{queryResult.map(createItem,this)}</ul>;
            }

            return  <ul onDragOver={this.DragOver}>{allitems.map(createItem,this)}</ul> ;
        }
    });
export default TodoList;
```

TodoListItem

```
    var React=require('react');


var TodoListItem = React.createClass({
getInitialState : function(){
            return {items:[{item:'',isDone:false,cost:0}]};
        },


    componentDidMount: function() {

  },

        ChangeHandler: function(e){
            this.setState({
              value: e.target.checked
            });
            this.props.children.isDone = e.target.checked;
        },
        RemoveHandler: function(){
           this.props.onRemove(this.props.value);
        },
        DragEndHandler : function(e){
                this.props.onDragEnd(e);
            },
        DragStartHandler : function(e){
                this.props.onDragStart(e);
        },
        render: function(){




            var _style = "line-through";
            var space="                                         ";
            if(!this.props.children.isDone)
            _style ="none";

    this.props.AllItems.items.map(function(todo)
        {

        console.log(todo.cost)
        return (

              <li data-id={this.props.value} 
                        key={this.props.value} draggable="true" onDragEnd={this.DragEndHandler}
                    onDragStart={this.DragStartHandler}><button type="button" className="close pull-right" aria-hidden="true" onClick={this.RemoveHandler}>&times;</button><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.ChangeHandler} defaultChecked={this.props.children.isDone} /><span style={{"textDecoration": _style}}>{todo.item}{todo.cost}</span></li>
            );
        },this)


        }
    });

export default TodoListItem;
```

I tried to wrap the code inside div tag also but it did not work

Pease guide

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77247773/4393351

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not returning anything from TodoListItem component, check the render method.

Either put the map part inside a div like this:

```
return(
    <div>
        {
            this.props.AllItems.items.map(function(todo){
                ....
            }
        }
    </div>
)
```

Or store the map result in a variable and return the final result, like this:

```
render(){
    let data = this.props.AllItems.items.map(function(todo){
        ....
    }

    return(
        <div> {data} </div>
    );
}
```

As suggested by @ivarni in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189925/map-function-does-not-return-anything-in-reactjs/45190050#comment77348121_45190050): The `<li>` elements are supposed to go inside a `<ul>` the `div` is not allowed there, so change the structure according to that i just provided a reason of the error.

**[Reference.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)**

Comment: Assuming the `<li>` elements are supposed to go inside a `<ul>` the `div` is not allowed there. See details [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element). You might consider not recommending they break the DOM spec :)

Comment: @ivarni thanks for pointing out that, but code was **TL;DR** so just checked the issue with map part, and gave the idea what's the issue, will edit the answer :)

Comment: Yeah, it was pretty painful to read it. The formatting didn't help either :)

Comment: yes i was also going to point out that.Thanks @ivarni and mayank for your help:)

Answer (score 1):

You return nothing in your TodoListItem render function. Your return is from the map callback. Wrap everything in a div and return it.

```
return (<div>
   {this.props.AllItems.items.map(function(todo)
    {

    console.log(todo.cost)
    return (

          <li data-id={this.props.value} 
                    key={this.props.value} draggable="true" onDragEnd={this.DragEndHandler}
                onDragStart={this.DragStartHandler}><button type="button" className="close pull-right" aria-hidden="true" onClick={this.RemoveHandler}>&times;</button><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.ChangeHandler} defaultChecked={this.props.children.isDone} /><span style={{"textDecoration": _style}}>{todo.item}{todo.cost}</span></li>
        );
    },this);}
</div>)
```

Comment: Assuming the `<li>` elements are supposed to go inside a `<ul>` the `div` is not allowed there. See details [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element). You might consider not recommending they break the DOM spec :)