# Reactjs map function does not render the component

Tags: reactjs

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmiR6.png)  I am trying to render the createCardHotels function;however, whenever I run it, nothing shows up. Any help will be appreciated.

I used map function to loop through the data and whenever I run it I can see on the console that there is the data. The problem is just the rendering part.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Container, Button, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem, Dropdown, DropdownToggle} from 'reactstrap';
import {Carousel} from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import styles from 'react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css';
import './selectHotel.css'
import Scroll from '../ScrollUp';
import {search} from '../../actions/search';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class SelectHotel extends Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state={
          dropdownOpen: false,
          hotels: []
      };
      this.toggleDropdown = this.toggleDropdown.bind(this);
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(state, props){
      if(props.hotels !== state.hotels)
        return{
            ...state,
            hotels: props.hotels
        }
        return null;
  }

  createCardHotels = () => {
     return this.state.hotels.map((hotel) => {
        return(
            <div key={hotel._id} className="card">
                <div className="row ">
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <Carousel autoPlay infiniteLoop>
                            <div>
                                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" className="w-100"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" className="w-100"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" className="w-100"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" className="w-100"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" className="w-100"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" className="w-100"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" className="w-100"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" className="w-100"/>
                            </div>
                        </Carousel>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-5 px-3">
                        <div className="card-block px-3">
                            <h3 className="card-title">{hotel.name}</h3> 
                            <p className="card-text">description</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-3 price">
                        <h1 className="reservation-price">$Price</h1>
                        <Button style={cssStyles.buttonRoom} bsStyle="primary">Choose Hotel</Button>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
            )}
        )
    }

  toggleDropdown() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen
    }));
  }

  render(){
      console.log(this.state)
      console.log(this.props)
    return(
        <div>
            <Container>
            <Scroll/>
            <div>
            <Dropdown className = 'sortbutton' size="lg" isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggleDropdown}>
              <DropdownToggle style={{backgroundColor: "white", borderColor: "grey" , color: "black"}} caret>
                  Sort By:
              </DropdownToggle>

              <DropdownMenu>
                <DropdownItem onClick={()=>{this.setSort("low");}}>
                  Price: Low to High
                </DropdownItem>

                <DropdownItem divider />

                <DropdownItem onClick={()=>{this.setSort("high");}}>
                  Price: High to Low
                </DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </Dropdown>
            </div>
            {this.createCardHotels()}
            <br></br>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const cssStyles = {
    buttonRoom:{
        backgroundColor: '#156bc1',
        border: '1px solid #156bc1',
        alignItems: 'left',
        boxShadow: 'inset 0 -2px 0 #063665',
        paddingLeft: '2rem',
        paddingRight: '2rem',
        fontSize: '0.8rem'
    }
  }

  const mapStatetoProps = state => {
    return {
        hotels: state.search.hotels
    };
  }

  export default connect(mapStatetoProps, {search})(SelectHotel);
```

EDIT:
[This is the image from console after I put console.log(this.state), console.log(this.props), it seems like there is data in this.props and not in this.state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcezF.png)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with add class names to JSX elements. You are using class to apply css styles with class names but class is reserved for creating class components in React so you need to use className

Wherever you see class on jsx elements change it to className

Also never forget to add key to the top parent jsx element when you render them in loop. If you have unique from data then set id from data as a key like I did below else use index as key

Change

```
  return this.state.hotels.map((hotel) => {
    return(
        <div class="card">
         ........
```

To

```
  return this.state.hotels.map((hotel) => {
    return(
        <div key={hotel.id} className="card">
         .......
```

Also

Change

```
   <h1 className="reservation-price">$Price</h1>
```

To

```
   <h1 className="reservation-price">{"$Price"}</h1>
```

For images you need to use require or import

Change

```
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" className="w-100"/>
```

To

```
  <img src={require("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400")} className="w-100"/>
```

Do the same for other images as well

Or import it like

```
  import text from "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400";

  <img src={text} className="w-100"/>
```

Comment: I just did exactly what you told me to do, but there was no success. Its still the same

Comment: Please edit your question and post the latest code in the question I will take a look

Comment: I included the updated code as well as the console snippet. By the way thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Change everything to className and check my updated answer. Let me know if you see any errors in console

Comment: After I replaced class to className, its still the same. The "$Price" is just a string, i didnt do anything with that yet. I will post the updated code again

Comment: I updated my answer. Please give a try you need to use require or import to import images in React

Comment: After I updated the code, now i have an error saying module not found.

Comment: look at the top to get the snippet of the error. I tried the way you posted and it didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Сould you please show your building file. May be a problem with file-loader.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled more than an hour to figure out this simple mistake.

Let me tell you with simple example..

**Map works in 2 format.**

1. If you are using curly braces `=> { return ..}` then it should return.

```
   <div>
      {items.map((item) => {
        return <div key={item.card.info.id}>{item.card.info.id}</div>;
      })}
   </div>
```

2. Otherwise use oval brackets `=> ( .. )` without return

```
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.card.info.id}>{item.card.info.id}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
```