# React component not getting rendered with map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My LinkItem component doesn't get rendered when loadAll() is called. It is only rendered after handleClick() or handleChange() is called.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
var Datastore = require("nedb");
var db = new Datastore({ filename: __dirname + "/userdata" });
db.loadDatabase(function(err) {

});

function LinkItem(props) {
  console.log("Rendered");
  return (
    <div>
      <a href={props.name}>{props.name}</a>
    </div>
  );
}

export default class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      link: "",
      data: [],
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.loadAll = this.loadAll.bind(this);
  }

  loadAll() {
    let loadData = [];
    db.find({ type: "link" }, function(err, docs) {
      docs.map(doc => loadData.push(doc.name));
    });
    this.setState({ data: loadData });
  }

  // add new item to data set
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      data: [...this.state.data, this.state.link]
    });
    const doc = { name: this.state.link, type: "link" };
    db.insert(doc, (err, docs) => {
      console.log("Inserted");
      console.log(docs);
    });
  }

  // handles form input changes
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ link: event.target.value });
  }
```

Here in the render function, I am using map to render each LinkItem component. However, they aren't being created at all when I check console.log at my LinkItem component. They only show up once handleClick, and handleChange is called.

```
  render() {
    const data = this.state.data;

      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.loadAll}>Load data</button>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.link}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add</button>
          {console.log(data)}
          {/* render each data */}
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <LinkItem name={item} key={index} />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }

}
```

Basically what I want to happen is when loadData is called, all the data is rendered in LinkItem components.

Note: this isn't a duplicate. I checked other questions in stackoverflow where they didn't have a return in the map function. That's not the case for me. It does end up  rendered only when other state values change.

EDIT: I was able to fix it by putting setState inside db find and changing the callback to an arrow function. For those of you using nedb with react this might help.

```
  loadAll() {
    db.find({ type: "link" }, (err, docs) => { // changed to arrow function
      this.setState({ data: docs.map(doc => doc.name)});
    });
  }
```

Comment: I added an answer for you: in a few words, **call `setState` inside `db.find` callback. I also added a few tips you can take.

Let me know if that worked for you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77247773/4393351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call to `setState` inside your callback, **after** the documents have been retrieved:

#### Code

```
loadAll() {
  let loadData = [];
  db.find({ type: "link" }, function(err, docs) {
    docs.map(doc => loadData.push(doc.name));
    this.setState({ data: loadData });
  });
}
```

Or just do:

```
loadAll() {
  db.find({ type: "link" }, function(err, docs) {
    this.setState({ data: docs.map(doc => doc.name)});
  });
}
```

The reason you have to do that is because `db.find` is an **asynchronous function** so, it will return inmediatly so `loadData` will be equal to `[]`.

You could also declare `loadAll` as **async** and use **await**:

```
loadAll() {
  const docs = await db.find({ type: "link" });
  this.setState({ data: docs.map(doc => doc.name) });
}
```

By the way, there are **a few tips** that will make your code shorter:

1. Use the [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax
2. Declare your functions as [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), this way you can get rid of the constructor if you create the `state` directly inside the class

The final code will be something like this:

#### Final code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

var Datastore = require("nedb");
var db = new Datastore({ filename: __dirname + "/userdata" });
db.loadDatabase(function(err) {

});

function LinkItem(props) {
    console.log("Rendered");
    return (
        <div>
            <a href={props.name}>{props.name}</a>
        </div>
    );
}

export default class List extends Component {
    state = {
        link: "",
        data: [],
    }

    loadAll = async () => {
        const docs = await db.find({ type: "link" });
        this.setState({ data: docs.map(doc => doc.name) });
    }

    // add new item to data set
    handleClick = () => {
        const { data, link } = this.state;

        this.setState({
            data: [...data, link]
        });

        const doc = { name: this.state.link, type: "link" };

        db.insert(doc, (err, docs) => {
            console.log("Inserted");
            console.log(docs);
        });
    }

    // handles form input changes
    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ link: event.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.loadAll}>Load data</button>
                    <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.link}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add</button>

                {console.log(data)}
                {/* render each data */}

                {data.map((item, index) => (
                    <LinkItem name={item} key={index} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Note that `render` does not need to be declared as an **arrow function** because it is **automatically bound by React**.

Let me know if this works, otherwise, tell me what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I used your first solution and second solution but I had to change function(err, docs) to an arrow function for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Your `db.find` function is asynchronous, your program will keep on going and not wait for it to finish :

```
  loadAll() {
    let loadData = [];
    db.find({ type: "link" }, function(err, docs) {
      docs.map(doc => loadData.push(doc.name));
    });
    this.setState({ data: loadData });
  }
```

You have 2 solution to fix it.

Putting your `setState` inside the callback :

```
  loadAll() {
    let loadData = [];
    db.find({ type: "link" }, function(err, docs) {
      docs.map(doc => loadData.push(doc.name));
      this.setState({ data: loadData });
    });
  }
```

Or awaiting your call :

```
  loadAll = async() => {
    let loadData = [];
    const docs = await db.find({ type: "link" });
    docs.map(doc => loadData.push(doc.name));
    this.setState({ data: loadData });
  }
```

Also, the map function will return a new array with your values. The following syntax is shorter and does the same thing :

```
loadAll = async () => {
    this.setState({ 
        data: (await db.find({ type: "link" })).map(doc => doc.name)
    });
}
```

I also noticed you were using your state values inside `setState`. React recommends using your previous state in a callback to do so and avoid unexpected behavior :

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        data: [...prevState.data, prevState.link]
    });
```

Another thing you could use is deconstruction, this code :

```
const data = this.state.data;
```

Could become :

```
const { data } = this.state;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your answer helped as well