# Print one of rendered components by map function

Tags: reactjs

I have a `Home` component that renders with a `map` function an array of `contact`s, each `contact` has its own print button and should print only its contact . The issue is that currently it prints the entire page and not just the `contact` which the print was clicked on.

I added a `isPrinting` state to the `contact` component, by default set to `false`, when the print button is being clicked it's being set to `true` and when the print dialog is being closed I set it back to false.

How can I actually make the print button to print only the contact that its print was click?

My `handlePrint` function on `contact` component:

```
  handlePrint = () => {
    this.setState({ isPrinting: true });
    window.print();
    window.onafterprint(
      this.setState({ isPrinting: false })
    );
  };
```

`map` function on `Home` component:

```
  contacts.map(info => (
              <SearchResultsPanel
                info={info}
                key={info.id}
              />
```

I'm using `'@media print'` to control the print styles.

Comment: Have you tried using setState callback in `this.setState({ isPrinting: true });`?

Comment: @blaz the `setState` is working as expected, when the user clicks on print the state changes to `true` and when he closes the print dialog it changes back to `false`, I'm asking here how to use this state to actually print only one of the contacts.

Comment: I asked above question since setState is asynchronous: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback - so there is no guarantee that the state is set yet at the time `window.print()` is executed.

Comment: The best solution could be to open contact alone in new window

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77247773/4393351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to by default hide on `@media print` every Contact component you display.

Then into your `<SearchResultsPanel>` component instance that you want to print out make append a css class that would override the `display: none` declaration that affect all the contact, using the `isPrinting` state you setup in this specific instance.

You also may want to use callbacks on setState to make sure the re-render caused by `this.setState({ isPrinting: true });` is done before the `window.print()` is triggered.

So you could do :

```js
handlePrint = () => {
    this.setState({ isPrinting: true }, () => {
        window.print();
        window.onafterprint(
            this.setState({ isPrinting: false })
        );
    });
};
```

or if you want to use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) :

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

// Set isPrinting value and its setter function
const [isPrinting, setIsPrinting] = useState(false)

// Your handlePrint function reshaped for hooks
const handlePrint = () => setIsPrinting(true)

// Callback when isPrinting is updated to true
useEffect(() => {
    if (isPrinting) {
        window.print();
        window.onafterprint(setIsPrinting(false));
    }
}, [isPrinting])
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed anser, it basically works, but when I closes the print dialog  it's break the page on this error (`TypeError: window.onafterprint is not a function`)