# Map not outputting anything, with no error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a small app that takes input from a text area and matches it up against a JSON file, with the purpose of only showing the JSON data that matches the input from the text area.

The `MakeList` function works pretty well (although it doesn't work until the "Output JSON" button is clicked twice, if anyone could help me understand that it'd be a bonus!). I could have the map in that function just create text nodes as it goes down the array, but I want to do it the React way. However, the map inside `#results-area` isn't doing anything, and I'm not sure why. There's no error message.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

let cardMasterList = require('./scryfall-oracle-cards.json')

function CardFinder() {

    let [listEntries, setListEntries] = useState([])

    function MakeList(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        setListEntries(document.querySelector('#entry-textarea').value.split('\n').sort())
        listEntries.map((theCard,cardItem) => {
            cardMasterList
                .filter(({name}) => name === theCard)
                .map((cardNameMap) => {
                    let cardData = JSON.stringify(cardNameMap)
                    console.log(cardData)
                    document.querySelector('#json-output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(cardNameMap)
                })
        })
    }

    function DontDoIt(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    return(
        <section id="card-finder-output">

            <form id="entry-form" onSubmit={() => {DontDoIt()}}>
                <textarea id="entry-textarea"></textarea>
                <button className="astbutton" onClick={MakeList}>Output JSON</button>
            </form>

            <aside id="results-area">
            {
                listEntries.map((theCard,cardItem) => {
                    cardMasterList
                        .filter(({name}) => name === theCard)
                        .map((cardNameMap) => {
                            return(<span key={cardItem}>{JSON.stringify(cardNameMap)}</span>)
                        })
                })
            }
            </aside>

            <aside id="json-output"></aside>
        </section>
    )

}

export default CardFinder
```

Once I have my output, I plan to just copy it to a text file and use it as a database for now - but I'll experiment with using an actual database later.

Comment: What is listEntries.length at that point?

Comment: Just checked, it's the proper number of entries.

Comment: That map and filter logic is pretty complex and all heavily dependent on specific data structures which may not match the real data. You might consider validating your data using React prop types or even just assertions. Might also consider breaking out the listEntries.map function into a separately declared function. Even if you fix the code some other way, those defensive programming techniques will help you later on when you forget what this code does or why it works.

Comment: Once I get it to actually output what I want, I can work on validation and whatnot. Any idea why it's not doing anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77247773/4393351

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
                listEntries.map((theCard,cardItem) => {
                    cardMasterList
                        .filter(({name}) => name === theCard)
                        .map((cardNameMap) => {
                            return(<span key={cardItem}>{JSON.stringify(cardNameMap)}</span>)
                        })
                })
```

I think you want:

```
                listEntries.map((theCard,cardItem) => (
                    cardMasterList
                        .filter(({name}) => name === theCard)
                        .map((cardNameMap) => {
                            return(<span key={cardItem}>{JSON.stringify(cardNameMap)}</span>)
                        })
                ))
```

Or:

```
                listEntries.map((theCard,cardItem) => {
                    return cardMasterList
                        .filter(({name}) => name === theCard)
                        .map((cardNameMap) => {
                            return(<span key={cardItem}>{JSON.stringify(cardNameMap)}</span>)
                        });
                })
```

The first one creates a filtered map of cardMasterList but then discards it. The latter two return a filtered, transformed cardMasterList (generating some HTML), which looks like what you intend.

I'm not sure if that's the only problem, because it also depends on how the data is shaped.

I also recommend doing some additional validation (via prop types or roll-your-own) and possibly unit tests to check the behavior of complex mapping/filtering like this. If you do it when you write the code in the first place, you may avoid some bugs and have an easier time reasoning through the logic (both now and when it's revisited, perhaps much later than you expect).

Comment: First one worked! I was tinkering with some validation (i.e. does the card name inputted match any of the names on the valid name list?) but I gave up - while I do want to know how to do that, this random JSON output thing only needs to work once.